# runAction in swift, make object follow a path

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-animation, uibezierpath

I'm trying to make an object follow a circular path every time I press a button, but it gives me an error in the last line that says **`UIImageView` does not have a member named `runAction`**. I already tried with `.addAnimation` but it still won't work.

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
let circle = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), cornerRadius: 100)
let followCircle = SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 5.0)
blueDot.runAction(SKAction(followCircle))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solely based on the short code snippet and on the fact that

> 'UIImageView' does not have a member named 'runAction'

I would say that the object `blueDot` is an `UIImageView` object and according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html), it doesn't have `runAction` method. Probably you have mistakenly assigned an `UIImageView` to that variable instead of `SKNode` or one of its subclasses.  You should probably check if that is so and fix the issue by assigning a proper `SKNode` object to it.